# how to display related list records from a parent object into the different child object

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have 3 objects, team, player and game. Look-up relationship between team and player and team and game. In both relationships, team is parent. What i want now is, I want to display all players names that are related to that team into the game object. I do not have any relation ship between game and player. Basically what i want is, for example, i have chosen real madrid as a team in game object using lookup relationship, and there are players that are related to real madrid, I want all those players to be displayed in game object. How is this possible using only UI without apex of VF. Since i am practicing UI only, It would be better if i have been told a way to do this only UI if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show team related list in game record page using related list single component. This will allow you too show the parent related list on a child record page in Lightning. This is not available in classic.

Read my blog on this:- https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/07/12/showing-parent-related-list-on-child-record-page-in-lightning-expereience/

Comment: thanks sanket. it helped.